# I want to extract data from string html in PHP

Tags: php

I have HTML string and I want to extract some data from that string.

```
<html>
<head>
</head
<body>
<!-- [slider id=1] --> 
<!-- [slider id=2] -->
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get all the ids then I will show my slider accordingly.
I tried with `preg_match` and `substr` after getting `strpos` in the loop but didn't get success

```
$str = $response->content();

        $needle1 = "[slider";
        $needle2 = "] -->";
        $lastPos1 = 0;
        $lastPos2 = 0;
        $ids = array();
        while (($lastPos1 = strpos($str, $needle1, $lastPos1))!== false && ($lastPos2 = strpos($str, $needle2, $lastPos2))!== false) {

            echo $lastPos1. ' '.$lastPos2. ' '. substr($str, $lastPos1, $lastPos2).'<br/>';

            $lastPos1 = $lastPos1 + strlen($needle1);

            $lastPos2 = $lastPos2 + strlen($needle2);


        }
Output:

2152 2164 [slider id=1] --> 
2192 2204 [slider id=2] --> 
2231 2243 [slider id=3] --> 
2270 2282 [slider id=4] -->
```

Comment: use an html parser

Comment: Use `preg_match_all("/<!--\s*\[slider\sid=(\d+)\]\s*-->/", $html, $matches)`

Comment: Thanks Mohammad thats works... thanks Jens too